# In Record of Lodoss War, how much time has passed from the beginning to the end of the series?

Tags: anime, record-of-lodoss-war

In the OVAs of the Record of Lodoss War, how much time takes place between the the first episode and the last one?

The [timeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_of_Lodoss_War#Characters) on Wikipedia appears to be for the original D&D games and stories, and not for the OVAs. It does note that NRC 510 is when the OAV continuity begins, but it doesn't say when it ends.

Comment: The timeline of events considered "current" in the OVA are intended to take place roughly over a 1 year period, sort of in accordance with its release schedule.

Comment: We know there is a roughly 7-10 year time skip between the time of Parn and Deelit's main adventure, and  when Spark took over. And the war with king Beld happened some 5 years before that.  A conservative estimation (based on my knowledge of the light novels and the OVA series, which started after the war with Beld) would put the entire saga at somewhere between 15 to 20 years, human time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I stated in my comment, the OVA takes place roughly over a **1 year** period, sort of in accordance with its release schedule. This is somewhat common with a series that is released monthly.

There are some closing events that occur that may place it closer to 1.5 years, perhaps even 2.

Hopefully you didn't want something month-accurate or better. This is actually quite a good question, as Lodoss' timeline is a bit contested outside of the DND transcripts.

**Complicated History:**

The difficulty with the Lodoss War timeline is that, as you have found, the only continuous timeline is from the DND transcripts.

From those transcripts they developed everything else to do with Lodoss. Of course, some events are cut out, some are skipped, and some are moved forward to happen earlier, with different characters.

The actual events in the OVA alone appear to take place in just over one year.

By the time the TV series came out, the producers realized how complicated following the timeline was going to be for viewers, and sort of gave up on trying to streamline it (like they did with the OVA). So in the TV series, the events are separated by almost 10 years, and people purchasing the box set got an explanation of the TV series timeline.

Of course, using this "defined" timeline to trace back into the OVA doesn't quite work, because they don't fit together. If they did, the timeline would be more like **10 to 12 years**, but clearly the 10 year gap doesn't fit anywhere in the series. This is evident as Parn never quite ends up being the *tenured* warrior we expect from the DND timeline or the TV timeline.